How to derive summation for given recurrence relation
I'm working on the following recurrence relation using the iteration technique:
() = ( − 1) + 
Here is my process using the technique and deriving a general solution:
my work with solution in red
My question comes down to the summation at the end. I do not understand why the correct summation starts at i = k + 1 and culminates at n when in my iterations there are really k terms (k - 1 terms when i begins at 0), each of the form n - i.
I don't see recurrence relations like this a lot, so I would like to know the logic that led to the correct solution (the key doesn't contain this info).

Are you sure you've got the right recurrence noted down? The solution in red text does not seem to make any sense just as you've deduced. Have you spoken with your course tutor or colleagues?
